# asp.Net MVC - Remove white space when running or before deploying

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a asp.Net MVC 4 projects .In My project only render big reports (use table html element)
So I have a considering :
Should I remove white space when running like as [How can I remove white-spaces from ASP.NET MVC# output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5197225/how-can-i-remove-white-spaces-from-asp-net-mvc-output)
or Remove all white space when I write html code .it' mean I will manually remove all white space in visual studio before deploying

Everybody help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that you are trying to get answer if the run-time solution (described in the link) won't be an issue in production, right? Well, as mentioned here:

[Memory Efficiency and Performance of String.Replace .NET Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/399798/)

you should do some own benchmarking. To be sure, that replacing chars of a `big report` for many users won't kill the performance.

But my suggestion is do it in run-time. Maybe better in AOP filter. **At once**, when all the response is finished (I am doing similar functionality replacing some strings).

```
public virtual void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext filterContext)
{
  // Change result as needed
  filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Filter = 
    new ResponseStream(filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Filter);
}
```

And here is the Stream

```
protected class ResponseStream : MemoryStream
{
    readonly Stream _stream;
    public ResponseStream(Stream stream)
    {
        _stream = stream;
    }

    public override void Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        //base.Write(buffer, offset, count);
        string html = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(buffer);

        // TODO - here remove spaces...

        byte[] outdata = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes(html);

        //write bytes to stream
        _stream.Write(outdata, 0, outdata.GetLength(0));
    }
}
```

The second think, could be enabling of the **dynamic compression** on your IIS (if using IIS 7.0 please read http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753681%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)